# PHP Authentication using text file

Tags: php, html, authentication

> So i have fixed the problem with the loop by placing the ifelse statement outside the for loop. So when it is true it is working fine. However when FALSE i get the following error!
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in webaddhidden.php on line 25 Invalid Login

I am new to PHP and am trying to make a simple login with a text file.

Error Message: if an incorrect username/password is entered :

> Invalid LoginInvalid LoginInvalid LoginInvalid Login Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in webaddhidden.php on line 25 Invalid Login

and if the correct username/password the error is:

> Invalid LoginMatch Found!

So it prints both the if and the ifelse statements.

Your help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!!!!

The code I am using is:

```
    <?php

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $matchFound = false; 

    $fileArray = array();

    $myFile = fopen("customers.txt", 'r');

        while(!feof($myFile) ) //reads  all lines of text file
    {
    $fileArray[] = fgets($myFile); 
    }

    fclose($myFile);

    for($lineCounter = 0; $lineCounter < count($fileArray); $lineCounter++)
        {
          $exploadedLine = explode("\t",$fileArray[$lineCounter]);

          if(trim($exploadedLine[2] == $username && trim($exploadedLine[3]) 
                   == $password))
        {

            echo 'Match Found!';
    $matchFound = true;
    break;

            }

        elseif($matchFound == false)
        {
    echo 'Invalid Login';
        }

      }
```

?>

Comment: Why are you using filing instead of database ? Is it a home work ?

Comment: Hint: `if(trim($exploadedLine[2] == $username && trim($exploadedLine[3]) 
                   == $password))`

Answer (score 0):

This block of code is actioned as the file is searched - inside the loop.

```
elseif($matchFound == false)
{
     echo 'Invalid Login';
}
```

It needs to be placed **outside** the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Few things you can do to fix/improve your code:

- You can use file() to directly read lines of text files into an array. http://www.php.net/function.file-get-contents
- Make sure indexes of are set in exploded array using isset() function to avoid notices in case the text file is not formatted as expected. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php
- Move the logic block checking invalid login out of the loop so that it doesn't print invalid error message each time the loop finds a mismatch.

Try using the code below:

```
<?php

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$matchFound = false;

$fileArray = file("customers.txt"); //reads all lines of text file

for ($lineCounter = 0; $lineCounter < count($fileArray); $lineCounter++) {
  $exploadedLine = explode("\t", $fileArray[$lineCounter]);

  if ((isset($exploadedLine[2]) && trim($exploadedLine[2]) == $username) &&
    (isset($exploadedLine[3]) && trim($exploadedLine[3]) == $password)) {
    echo 'Match Found!';
    $matchFound = true;
    break;
  }

}

if ($matchFound === false) {
  echo 'Invalid Login';
}
?>
```